# Session timeout after inactivity in express-session in Express server

Tags: node.js, express

I want to expire the session after 1 min of inactivity. I tried the following

```
 app.use(session({
     secret: config.sessionSecret,
     cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
     store: new mongoStore({
        db: db.connection.db,
        collection: config.sessionCollection
     })
 }));
```

The session is expiring exactly after 1 min the user logs in even if the user continues to use the application. I have been unable to set it to expire *after 1 min of inactivity*. Any ideas? Thanks in advance again.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you've resolved your issue but I had the same issue and I'd like to post what fixed it here in case it can benefit anyone.

It seems that the default expires will end the session after the specified length of time regardless of what the user is doing but if you include resave and rolling variables it will only expire after it has been idle for the specified length of time.

```
var express = require("express");
var session = require("express-session");

var app = express();

app.use (
    session ({
        secret: "53cr3t50m3th1ng",
        resave: true,
        rolling: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            expires: 30 * 1000
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in connect. See this issue:

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/670

Comment: Tried and it did not work. The session still times out after 1 min after login.

Answer (score 0):

I know it too late to answer on this query but may it will help someone else.

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
name: 'farmerApp',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {
    expires: 120000
}
}));
```